# MarkLogic XPath on JSON with "@" symbol in property name

Tags: json, xpath, marklogic

I am dealing with some JSON-LD data in MarkLogic and have trouble using XPath on property names with "@" symbol. For example:

```
{
  "@type": "News",
  "title": "some title",
  "description": "some description"
}
```

My goal is to retrieve the title if the type is "News". I understand "@" is reserved to represent attribute in XPath, so something below should not work.

```js
doc.xpath('.[@type="News"]/title')
```

With the `xdmp.encodeForNCName` function, I see the "@" symbol is represented as `_40_` in the JSON representation. But it still doesn't work.

```js
doc.xpath('.[_40_type="News"]/title')
```

Comment: As a usage note:  encodeForNCName is a utility function designed to encode arbitrary strings as valid NC Names.  One place this is used is in the JSON to XML transformation library.  This does not imply that its used natively in doc.xpath (which does not 'convert' your json document )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `fn:name()` would work too, as suggested by the other answers, you can address nodes with funny spelling in MarkLogic XPath directly too. Probably a deviation from the official XPath standard itself, but MarkLogic allows writing expressions like:

```
doc.xpath('node("@type")[. eq "News"]/title'
```

Very useful for JSON properties containing spaces and such as well..

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

You could test the `name()` in a predicate:

```
doc.xpath('.[*[contains(name(), "@type")] = "News"]/title')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dirty solution.

```
 .[@*[name() = '@type']][@*='News']/title
```

I know you are working with json, but I just checked the xpath in html with similar attribute and value combination. You can see the xpath considered both attribute name and value (as it's not selecting other node with the same name but different value).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @supputuri. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in MarkLogic: `xdmp.toJSON({"@type": "News", "title": "some title"}).xpath('.[@*[name()="@type"]][@*="News"]/title')`